# Selecting Correct Answer When Adding Questions To Database Via HTML Form

Tags: php, html

I have a form which has the question and 4 answers (it's a quiz), I tried to comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/29280091/6482242 but I don't have enough reputation yet. This is very similar to what I have (as well as [How to set the correct answer via checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30072262/6482242) ).

The layout that I have is:

```
<label for="question_text">Question Text:</label>
<textarea title="Insert Question Text" name="question_text"></textarea>

<h4>Check Correct answer -></h4>
<input type="radio" name="correct_answer_flag" value="1">
<label for="correct_answer_flag, answer_1">Answer One:</label>
<input type="text" title="Enter Answer" name="answer_1" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="radio" name="correct_answer_flag" value="1">
<label for="correct_answer_flag, answer_2">Answer Two:</label>
<input type="text" title="Enter Answer" name="answer_2" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="radio" name="correct_answer_flag" value="1">
<label for="correct_answer_flag, answer_3">Answer Three:</label>
<input type="text" title="Enter Answer" name="answer_3" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="radio" name="correct_answer_flag" value="1">
<label for="correct_answer_flag, answer_4">Answer Four:</label>
<input type="text" title="Enter Answer" name="answer_4" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Question" name="question_submit" />
```

There is some PHP in the background to grab these and put them into a database, but I need to know please what the correct syntax is to link a radio button to a text input?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: You mean to say, if the answer added by user is correct, you want to get the radio button selected?

Comment: They add the 4 answers and select the correct one with the radio button.

Comment: the 'correct_answer_flag' radios shouldn't have all the same value!

Comment: I made them the same because the flag is 1 and I don't know which answer they're going to select. What should I have done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the values of radio buttons and then store its value to a separate column in table with column something like `correct_answer`

```
<label for="question_text">Question Text:</label>
<textarea title="Insert Question Text" name="question_text"></textarea>

<h4>Check Correct answer -></h4>
<input type="radio" name="correct_answer_flag" value="1">
<label for="correct_answer_flag, answer_1">Answer One:</label>
<input type="text" title="Enter Answer" name="answer_1" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="radio" name="correct_answer_flag" value="2">
<label for="correct_answer_flag, answer_2">Answer Two:</label>
<input type="text" title="Enter Answer" name="answer_2" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="radio" name="correct_answer_flag" value="3">
<label for="correct_answer_flag, answer_3">Answer Three:</label>
<input type="text" title="Enter Answer" name="answer_3" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="radio" name="correct_answer_flag" value="4">
<label for="correct_answer_flag, answer_4">Answer Four:</label>
<input type="text" title="Enter Answer" name="answer_4" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit Question" name="question_submit" />
```

And in that column just store the number of the selected Radio. So with each question, you will be storing 4 options, and among those 4 there will be one correct answer and its index will be stored in a separate table where you store you answer options.

Comment: Thank you for this! In the database, it's been set up that the wrong answers all have 0 as the flag and the correct answer has 1. This is why I made all of them 1. In the PHP, I was going to say, ok, that's the flag, make all the others 0 when inserting them into the database. How can I change this please?

Comment: To give you accurate answer I need to know your DB table structure. Are you storing questions and answers in separate tables?

Comment: Yes, they're separate.

Comment: ok, so if you go with my suggestion, I would say to store `correct_answer` into the question table in a separate column. So when the question would be presented, you can compare the posted answer with the value in the answer column.